# Bruce Wayne’s pre Batman love interests

Tags: dc, history-of, batman, love

Has Bruce Wayne dated any girl before becoming Batman or he only trained and had no time for them ? if he has then how many had he dated?

Comment: This can be very broad.

Comment: @Clockwork - Excessively so. There have been multiple comics set before Batman became Batman

Comment: Even if you only restrict it to the movies, or even just the live-action movies, there's dozens of them - mostly unnamed though.  Bruce was a billionaire playboy before donning the cape.  I guess it begs the question of whether he really *dated* or just slept around a lot.  But almost any time you see Bruce in any kind of social event, he's basically surrounded by gorgeous women - pretty sure they're not just for show...

Comment: The fact that Bruce is shown to be surrounded by women in some scenes doesn't necessarily mean that he's actually dating any of them. If there's a large group, he's almost certainly not dating all of them at the same time, and if there are multiple women present that he isn't dating, it's perfectly reasonable to believe he's not strictly dating any of them. After all, if he were officially dating a specific woman, it'd be odd for him to bring a bunch of other female groupies on the date as well. I doubt his actual date in such a scenario would appreciate that.

Comment: Providing this is limited to women who were clearly stated to be dating or in a relationship with Bruce, prior to him becoming Batman, or shown to be on what looks like a one-on-one date with him, I doubt this list would be unreasonably long. I wouldn't personally count examples of him being surrounding by nameless women while attending a social event as clear examples of him dating anyone.

Comment: @LogicDictates "When I was younger, women used to throw themselves at my feet all the time. I stepped over them." - Old Bruce to Terry

Answer (score 11):

In the DC Animated Universe, in the animated movie [Batman: Mask of the Phantasm (1993)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%3A%20Mask%20of%20the%20Phantasm), we are told about the story of how he started out as Batman.

Initially, he was tempted to become the caped crusader we know. But after meeting Andrea Beaumont at the graveyard while visiting his parents' gravestone, they started having a mutual interest for each other. Bruce was ready to give up all his projects and live his life happily with her.

Eventually, though, she broke up with him and he donned the cape, becoming Batman.

Here's a small excerpt where you can see how troubled he is between becoming Batman, or deciding to live a happy life. It begins with him trying to come up with a design for his costume.

And this is when she sends him a breakup letter and he decides to become Batman (from a flashback).

Comment: RIP Kevin Conroy.

Comment: Zatanna would also qualify in TAS as i recall https://batmantheanimatedseries.fandom.com/wiki/Zatanna

Comment: @lucasbachmann Yeah, if I remember, Zatanna can be an honorable mention, because she had something for him while he was training to become Batman (so before he was), although they didn't say whether or not he liked her too. Until Batman Beyond when you realise he had a picture of her among all the women who had a special place in his heart. I hesitated to add her in. But I figured I'll let someone else write a separate answer about her, since I don't entirely remember her origin episode either.

Answer (score 2):

Christopher Nolan's Batman likely did not meaningfully date, especially not the kind of shallow pretty women that he is seen to be dating while hiding his Batman persona.

When we first meet him, he has intentionally locked himself up in a prison with the sole goal to beat up those who deserve it. He is intentionally ruining his life in pursuit of his anger about what happened.

While we don't particularly hear about his life between leaving Gotham (and Rachel) and seeing him in the Chinese prison; we can infer from Alfred's comments and behavior that he was very worried for Bruce's mental wellbeing at the time, and we can infer that this version of Bruce clearly was driven by instinct and revenge rather than an idealized ideal of justice and vigilantism (like the 90's incarnations of Batman tended to be).

In light of that, it seems highly unlikely that this Bruce was capable of a genuine relationship.

Comment: In the Nolan films though, Bruce didn't start training to become Batman until he graduated from college, so he lived a relatively normal life (for a rich kid) up to the age of 21 or so. It'd be surprising if he never had a girlfriend at any time during his high school or college years, although I don't recall any being specified in the movies themselves.

Comment: I like Nolan's DK trilogy, but it gives us a very limited scope of Bruce Wayne compared to the comics and other media. I wouldn't use that as a basis for judging Bruce Wayne as a character.

Comment: @JakeL The OP didn't specify a specific incarnation, and there are some distinct differences between the incarnations. It really depends which Bruce OP is thinking of.